# How to access current state on Redux Toolkit on createAsyncThunk

Tags: reactjs, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

So i want access current state of my state on `state.formLogin` to store in variable `userCredentials` how can i can access my state on createAsyncThunk?

```
export const loginAsync = createAsyncThunk(
  "user/login",
  async () => {
    try {
      const { content } = await login(userCredentials);
      localStorageHelpers.setUserToken(content.token);
      localStorageHelpers.setUserId(content.userId);
      return content.userId;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  }
);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access the whole state by calling `thunkAPI.getState()`. See [PayloadCreator](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#payloadcreator)

```
export const loginAsync = createAsyncThunk(
  "user/login",
  async (_, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      // const state = thunkAPI.getState();
      const { content } = await login(userCredentials);
      localStorageHelpers.setUserToken(content.token);
      localStorageHelpers.setUserId(content.userId);
      return content.userId;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  }
);
```